# Can I use this power supply with my motherboard

Tags: power-supply

So this is my first post so I apologize in advance if this is either a dumb question or a novice one.

I am trying to figure out some things about my power supply. I have purchased this power supply http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817438014

To go with it, I purchased this motherboard:
http://www.microcenter.com/product/427160/GA-78LMT-USB3_Socket_AM3_mATX_760G_AMD_Motherboard

The power connector on the PSU is 20+4 pin. Which from my understanding it is compatible with both 24 pin and 20 pin connectors on the motherboard. Please correct me if I am wrong on that. I am a little concerned on the motherboard because it also has an 8 pin atx power supply. Now the power supply has (2) 6+2 pin connectors on it. Can I put that in the motherboard or no?

Again, I apologize for the novice question and I appreciate the answers! This is my first build and I don't want to mess it up! :)

I will be running a Geforce 950 and a AMD 8320e and 32gb of ram.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. It should work. Modern motherboards have essentially be standardized for years, and the 6+2 merely means you have a little clip-on bit so the same connector works with lower power and higher power CPU requirements.

The 6+2 connector would go to higher end Graphics Cards, while the 4+4 connector would go to the small connector by the CPU.

Comment: Interestingly the ATX motherboard configuration specification was introduced in 1995, more than two decades ago. Wow.

Comment: Journeyman geek, it says PCI express connector. What does that mean

Comment: Its for your video card. Some do a single connector, some do two. 950 may not need it at all.

Comment: Buts its still okay that I put the 6+2 connector into the 8 pin atx power connector spot? I may be repeating myself and I'm sorry for that lol

Comment: No, won't fit. There's a specific CPU power connector, usually labelled EATX 12V or something

Comment: so do I need a difference PSU?

Comment: The connector should be there. Its *standard*

Comment: according to the specifications, 

1 x 20+4-Pin ATX
1 x 4+4-Pin EPS12V
2 x 6+2-Pin PCI-E
6 x SATA
3 x Molex
1 x FDD

Comment: " 4+4-Pin EPS12V" yeah, that goes into the connector next to your CPU.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I appreciate it! If I have any other questions I'm coming directly to you. You're very helpful!